# Submit form with ajax and hide the from on sucess

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I've `form` where i should submit `name` and `suffix` how to use ajax to `send data to php file` that would check it out and if there is error will send back the error and if no error it would submit it and send back success message and the form will hide.

**HTML Form Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" name="myform">
Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<br />
Suffix : <input type="text" name="suffix" id="suffix"/>
<br />
<input id="Submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="thanks" />
</form>
```

This should submit informations to the following PHP file to be checked and show results

**PHP Code**

```
<?PHP
require_once("config.php"); // db connection

$name = $_POST['name'];
$suffix = $_POST['suffix'];

if(empty($suffix) || empty($name) ){

echo "All input are needed"; // this error

} else if($name == 'john') {

echo "sorry john not here"; // this error

} else {

$qry="select * from users where username='$name'";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die($qry);
$line=mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $line['email']; // this success
}
?>
```

I also wonder if it it passed and sent back success message can the input form be hidden

~ thanks for help

Comment: Specify a callback function in your AJAX request (via jQuery, XHR, or other library) and have it access the `<form>` element to hide and make the CSS change of `display: none;`.  At the same time you could also display your success/fail message (or whatever) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some of the answers say, you could avoid using a form.

Here's an approach to achieve what you want, by responding JSON from the server.

The HTML:

```
<div id="myform" name="myform">
    Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <br />
    Suffix : <input type="text" name="suffix" id="suffix"/>
    <br />
    <button id="Submit" type="button">thanks</button>
</div>
```

I turned the `form` tag into a `div`, and the `submit` tag into a `button`.

The Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // The url where the data will be submitted to
    var url = '/submit/url';

    $('#Submit').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            // Take values from form inputs
            data: {
                name:   $('#name').val(),
                suffix: $('#suffix').val()
            }
        }).done(function(r){
            if (r.success) {
                // success.
                // hide form container, alert email.
                $('#myform').hide();
                alert(r.email);
            } else {
                // else, there was an error
                alert(r.error);
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Upon clicking the button, an Ajax request will be executed and when done, the JSON response will be analyzed.

Finally, the PHP:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php"); // db connection

$name   = $_POST['name'];
$suffix = $_POST['suffix'];

if (empty($suffix) || empty($name)) {
    $resp = array('error' => "All input are needed"); // this error
} elseif ($name == 'john') {
    $resp = array('error' => "sorry john not here"); // this error
} else {
    $qry="select * from users where username='$name'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry) or die($qry);
    $line=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    // this success
    $resp = array(
        'success' => true,
        'email'   => $line['email']
    );
}

// Set content type to JSON and output the array, JSON-encoded.
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($resp);
```

The request will output a JSON object that can contain as much data as you want, that can be easily analyzed in Javascript.

Comment: that was very helpful to me as case of study and made me understand some points ~ thanks a lot

Comment: But the question was using mysql. Would it be right to change the answer to use a different library?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
      $("#myform").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var name=$('#name').val();
      var suffix=$('#suffix').val();

      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: 'script.php',
        data: 'name='+name+'&suffix='+suffix,
        cache: false,
        success:function(html)
          {
            if($.trim(html)=='Your error condition')
            { //do something }

           else { $('#myform').hide(); }

           }
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to send an ajax request you don't want to use the standard form submit. Instead you want to send the name and suffix values to the server using XHR. Most javascript libraries offer a simple way to create the ajax call. You could try JQuery and use it's $.ajax() function. This method accepts an OnSuccess callback that  you could use to hide the form after the ajax call returns successfully. You can check out the documentation on how to do this on the JQuery website.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

The hard part as it stands is going to be determining whether the output is valid or represents an error. Unless you hard code those messages into your client it's going to be tricky.

What you probably want to do is use [HTTP response codes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) in your PHP and return some kind of error code (maybe 500?) if there is an error.

Then, you can use error handling on your client and detect whether it is a success or not. [JQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method will automatically detect this and call the success or error callbacks accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this, and modify it with your statements. Hopefully this puts you in the correct direction.

```
  $('FORM-ID').submit(function(event) {

    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: form.attr('method'),
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
       // On Success
    }).fail(function() {
      // On Fail
    });
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myform input#submit').on('click',function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  var data={}

  $('#myform').find('[name]').each(function(index, value){

    var that=$(this);
    var name=that.attr('name');
    var value=that.val();
    data[name]= value;

 });

 $.ajax({

  url: 'myfile.php',
  data: data,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(response)
  {
     if(response=="All inputs are needed")
     {
        alert(response);
     }

     else if(response=="Sorry John not here")
     {
        alert(response);
     }

     else{ alert("email is "+response); $('#myform').hide();}

  }
 })

})
```